# Adding Function for Every non-None Parameters with And Operator

Tags: python, function

I want to combine functions with non-None parameters with `and`. 
Suppose I have this function:
`def foo(a,b,c)`
For every non-None parameter, I want to call a function, for example `bar` and linked with `and`. But if all of the parameters are `None`, So, in the example, the result will be having 6 combinations like this:

```
if a is not None and b is not None and c is not None:
    return bar(a) and bar(b) and bar(c)
elif a is None and b is not None and c is not None:
    return bar(b) and bar(c)
elif a is not None and b is None and c is not None:
    return bar(a) and bar(c)
elif a is not None and b is not None and c is None:
    return bar(a) and bar(b)
elif a is None and b is None and c is not None:
    return bar(c)
elif a is None and b is not None and c is None:
    return bar(b)
elif a is not None and b is None and c is None:
    return bar(a)
else:
    return True
```

How do I do this without listing all of the possible combinations of parameters? For example, is it possible to do something like this? (`+=` symbolizes `and`)

```
func = ...
if a is not None:
    func += bar(a)
if b is not None:
    func += bar(b)
if c is not None:
    func += bar(c)
if all of them wrong:
    return True
else:
    do func
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the result of `and`ing these arguments, you can just use `all()` and filter out the `None`s:

```
def bar(n):
    return n

def foo(a,b,c):
    return all(bar(arg) for arg in [a, b, c] if arg is not None)

foo(None, True, True)
# True

foo(False, True, None)
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args` to pack variable parameters and iterate through them. I assume that `bar` returns a boolean, allowing us to use `&=`.

```
def foo(*args):
    result = True
    for param in args:
        if param is not None:
            result &= bar(param)
    return result
```