# Adding Different Function for Every non-None Parameters with And Operator

Tags: python, function

This question is similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160789/adding-function-for-every-non-none-parameters-with-and-operator), but I forgot one detail to it.
I want to combine **different** functions with non-None parameters with and. Suppose I have this function: `def foo(a,b,c)`. For every non-None parameter, I want to call a different function and linked with and. But if all of the parameters are None, it must return `True`. **The functions will return boolean and are already defined with the respecting parameters. ** For example, let the functions associated with a is `bar_1`, b is `bar_2` and c is `bar_3`. Then the result will be having 7 combinations like this:

```
if a is not None and b is not None and c is not None:
    return bar_1(a) and bar_2(b) and bar_3(c)
elif a is None and b is not None and c is not None:
    return bar_2(b) and bar_3(c)
elif a is not None and b is None and c is not None:
    return bar_1(a) and bar_3(c)
elif a is not None and b is not None and c is None:
    return bar_1(a) and bar_2(b)
elif a is None and b is None and c is not None:
    return bar_3(c)
elif a is None and b is not None and c is None:
    return bar_2(b)
elif a is not None and b is None and c is None:
    return bar_1(a)
else:
    return True
```

How do I do this without listing all of the possible combinations of parameters? For example, is it possible to do something like this? (+= symbolizes and)

func = ...

```
if a is not None:
    func += bar_1(a)
if b is not None:
    func += bar_2(b)
if c is not None:
    func += bar_3(c)
if all of them wrong:
    return True
else:
    do func
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link a list of functions with a list of values using the `zip` function, for instance:

```py
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return x - 1

def f3(x):
    return x - 2

def foo(a, b, c):
    return all(f(x) for f, x in zip([f1, f2, f3], [a, b, c]) if x is not None)
```

For instance, you get:

```py
>>> foo(None, None,None)
True
>>> foo(2, 1, 0)
False
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
True
>>> foo(0, 0, 0)
False
```

Of course, you can also drop `zip` and use tuples instead:

```py
def foo(a, b, c):
    return all(f(x) for f, x in [(f1, a), (f2, b), (f3, c)] if x is not None)
```